# application:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation: called with a null url

Tags: ios, ios6

I need my iOS app to handle custom URL schemes, e.g., `myapp://d1/d2`.

I set the `URL Types`in my app's `info.plist` and implemented the required delegate method:

```
-(BOOL) application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation
 {
    ...
 }
```

I run my app, then switch to Safari (thus my app runs in the background). In Safari I open URL `myapp://d1/d2`.  As a result my app pops to the foreground as advertised and the method above is called.  The problem is that that all its parameters (`application`, `url`, `sourceApplication` and `annotation`) are null.

After spending some time and not getting any non-null parameters, I tried to replace the method above with the depreciated `application:handleOpenURL:`

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url {
    ...
}
```

That worked.  The `url` parameter is exactly what I typed in Safari.

Obviously I don't want to use a depreciated method.  What am I doing wrong?

Running on iPad with iOS 6.1.3, and on a simulator.

Comment: Seeing the same issue. I wonder if the URL is not conforming to standards perhaps.